# PHP file_get_contents throws "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" within 5-10 seconds when accessing large xml file

Tags: php, apache, http, timeout, file-get-contents

I'm trying to load a file ("http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-YX458DZO75EQACZ3/xml") with file_get_contents but I'm getting an error within 5-10 seconds.  The xml file loads fine in a browser, and if I use a smaller version of it (adding "/future" on the end of the above url) it loads fine with file_get_contents.

The script is:

```
$file = "http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-YX458DZO75EQACZ3/xml";
$data = file_get_contents($file);
```

One of two errors show up, either:

```
Warning: file_get_contents("http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-YX458DZO75EQACZ3/xml") [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in MY_PHP_SCRIPT.php on line 2
```

Or:

```
Warning: file_get_contents("http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-YX458DZO75EQACZ3/xml") [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out  in MY_PHP_SCRIPT.php on line 2
```

Any ideas?  I've tried [using cURL instead](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/697540/revisions), but when I do that I just get "Error on line 1".  The error shows up in less then 10 seconds, so I can't imagine it's a timeout issue, since those defaults are generally 15 seconds or 30 seconds depending on the app.

Comment: when you used cURL from the link you showed - did you change:
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
to:
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
?

Answer (score 0):

//use this for your xml feed works fine

$load = file_get_contents('http://artistdata.sonicbids.com/ari-herstand/shows/xml/');

print_r($load);

Comment: Nice to know about the new URL for artistdata, but I still get the same error when I use it.  Are there any default timeout values at 15 seconds or less that I could increase?

Comment: It's best to use the url that artistdata.com provides. That's what they want you to use, and that's what should continue to work even if they were to move the actual data to another url.

Comment: @Micah .....if that site is updating means the results means ,, you can make a refresh at 15 seconds once.....so that you can get the updated results

Comment: Arjan, will do (it's possible they've updated their xml feed url since they were bought by sonicbirds).  Sam, I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you re-word that?

Comment: @Micah No,if there is timeout values at 15 secs ,we still can make update our php file too..

Answer (score 0):

1. file_get_contents() returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to maxlen bytes
2. An E_WARNING level error is generated if either maxlength is less than zero, or if offset exceeds the length of the stream.

Comment: That's not applicable since both offset and maxlength are not specified.

Comment: There is a default maxlength which your file probably went above. Try a smaller XML file and if it works good - you'll know that that's the case.

Comment: Most of the chances are that it either times-out or that the size is too big.
If you want to make it work, use cURL

Comment: Well, it works on my machine with the two lines of code from the question (note that it's not me who's asking the question).

Comment: @alfasin As Arjan said, I'm pretty sure this should be working.  I feel like there's just some default timeout that's set somewhere in the server config (that I don't have access to), since the code I posted works for smaller XML files at the same domain. (and the exact URL works for others even though it's very large).  I've read about a 15 sec apache timeout, is there any way to temporarily change that in PHP?

Comment: @Micah I'm also pretty sure it's time out. what platform are you working on ? windows ?